# Set Header Text of Hierarchical Grid By Data Field - Telerik C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I'm creating a Hierarchical grid using a template like this:

```
GridViewTemplate template = new GridViewTemplate();
template.DataSource = query;
GridViewTextBoxColumn txtcolumn = new GridViewTextBoxColumn();
txtcolumn.FieldName = "Mobile";
txtcolumn.Name = "colMobile";
txtcolumn.HeaderText = "Mobile Number";
template.Columns.Add(txtcolumn);
```

as you can See Header Text is just a simple `string`, How can I bind it to a `field` of `DataSource`? Possible?

Comment: If you're asking how to bind the column headers to the same datasource as the grid, I don't think it's going to be that easy.  Before you set the data source of the grid you can programmatically set the header text from the data in code manually.

Answer (score 0):

**FieldName** property of a column is actually used to bind a column to a datasource field.

For example, let's say your datasource contains two fields, **ID** and **UserName**.

If you want to add a column in the **RadGridView** that will reflect **UserName** field and its values, only thing you have to do is to set **FieldName = "UserName"** for your column.

**HeaderText** property is used to set column header text of your column that will be displayed in your application.

For example, if you want to add a column that would show **UserName** field value but the column name will be displayed as **User Name**, you have to set **FieldName = "UserName"** and **HeaderText = "User Name"**.

Comment: I have tested it, `Hearder Text = "UserName"` will show "UserName" in header not its value.

Comment: @Nofuzy, Yes, **HeaderText** does not bind columns to datasource field. **FieldName** property is there for that purpose, as I mentioned in my answer. Can you please tell in a bit details about the problem you are facing?

Comment: I know `FiledName` will read the value, but I need to bind the value to HeaderText, not just a simple `string`. for example if UserName value is "Ehsan", then I expect `HeadetText = "UserName"`, change Header Text to "Ehsan".

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Is it a hierarchical grid, that you were implementing? For example, if you click on a cell, should it expand to another grid and you want that grid header to be this cell value? or, upon clicking a cell, you want the main grid's header to be changed to field value? For, any one of those purposes, I think you can handle Telerik provided events and implement your behavior easily. [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/events_t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radgridview.htm) is a list of events for RadGridView.